# Temporarily change log level for all syslog calls

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I have a #define macro that accepts a syslog log priority and a string, then calls the syslog function passing the same parameters. This macro is used throughout my code to log when unexpected return values have occurred.

My problem is I have a function (lets call it myfunc()) that gets called only once, when my application starts up. There is a critical section as part of this function where I need all syslog calls for all other functions called here, to be logged in LOG_ALERT level. The functions called in this critical section make use of the #define macro in different places.

Is there a way to temporarily change either the syslog priority for all syslog calls to be LOG_ALERT level during execution of critical section in myfunc(), or temporarily update the #define macro so that all syslog calls become LOG_ALERT during this critical section? My first attempt was a global variable that gets set/cleared at the start/end of the critical section in myfunc(), then check for this variable in my #define logging macro. However, this is not suitable as I have observed this slows down other parts of my application which makes use of the #define macro to log unexpected return values.

Basically, including the following line in my #define logging macro causes certain problems so I would like to temporarily change the macro during critical section of myfunc():

```
int prio = (global_var ? LOG_ALERT : orig_priority)
```

Comment: Use a variable instead of using e.g. `LOG_ALERT` directly in the call?

Comment: *I have observed this slows down other parts of my application*. Really? Checking a single variable really makes a significant performance difference to your app? That check should be dwarfed by the cost of the logging itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it slows down other parts of my application as the macro is called in other places. Basically I need a way to temporarily change the macro only for this critical section (but C does not allow this).

Comment: Have you really *measured* it to be a significant bottleneck in your application? Or is it just something you *believe*?

Comment: And when I say variable, I mean a single global variable for the log-level itself. Defined and initialized like `int current_log_level = LOG_INFO;`. Then in your "critical" section reassign as `current_log_level = LOG_ALERT;` and reassign back to the old level once done. No conditions, just a simple variable to be passed in the `syslog` call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I measured it by repeatedly testing it without the line of code I added in my macro that I have just included and the problem does not show up. As soon as the line of code is added to the macro, the problem comes up again. The problem is certain DMA operations performed by my application get skipped, eg packet transfer ends up with corrupted bytes.

Comment: Correlation is not causation. Smells more like undefined behaviour in other parts of your code. I would not ignore that and instead debug it directly.